# How to Add Claim to ApplicationUser in custom SignInManager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

Converting my MVC app to utilize AspNet Identity. I have created an ApoplicationSignInManager class that extends SignInManager

I am overriding CreateIdentityAsyc and I want to add custom claims here without persisting to db so that the values are available for logged in users.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager, IUserService userService)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var myUser = userService.GetUser(user.Id);

        var userIdentity = user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);

        userIdentity.Result.AddClaim(new Claim("MyCustomID", myUser.CutomID.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the app hangs when executing the AddClaims line. I am guessing this has something to do with a deadlock from async task but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Please give me some guidance.

Comment: If it hangs then it must be a threading issue. use await on user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync

Comment: You should be `await`ing the call to `GenerateUserIdentityAsync()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`await`** before **`GenerateUserIdentityAsync`** method.

```
public async override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    ...

    var userIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    ...
}
```